# Accessing media file in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.11

I have this root

```
project
   polls
       data
          xml_files
             x.xml
```

I have added

```
MEDIA_URL = '/data/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/data/xml_files/'
```

and I have added

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'', include('web.urls')),
]  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I try

> localhost:8000/data/fuzzy.xml

it sends `404 page not found` with `/data/xml_files/FuzzyMirab1.xml` does not exist

How can I access that?

Comment: try including polls folder?

Comment: Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Do you use Django development server (`runserver` command)? In that case ensure that `DEBUG` is set to `True`.

Comment: i had tried MEDIA_URL=/polls/data/xml_files/ ut it didnt work. and i am sure django.contrib.staticfiles is included.

Comment: yes i use runserver

Comment: Your MEDIA_ROOT is an absolute path, not a relative path. Try changing that

Comment: thanks i used MEDIA_URL = '/data/xml_filse/' and MEDIA_ROOT = 'polls/data/xml_files/'

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to move data folder to the root directory of your project:

```
project
   data
       xml_files
           x.xml
   polls
```

And remove slash from the beginning of the `MEDIA_ROOT`:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'data/xml_files/'
```

Or you can use `polls/data/xml_files/` without moving the directory but it looks like a bad architecture for me.

As @Mikhail Burshteyn suggested you can also use absolute path:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/project/polls/data/xml_files/'
```